# update server database from localhost

Tags: mysql

I am using codeigniter, php and mysql, for project management we use SVN, from which we can update and commit project, and it reflects on the server automatically, But if I made any change in localhost database, I have to update it on server database manually. I am wondering if there is any tool or method to update the server database automatically from localhost, like svn commit.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this in Macromedia Dreamweaver where a project can be linked to a remote ftp site, and update option can be set to autosync (ie when you make changes in local copy it uploads to server automatically), probably netbeans also supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat for mysql and use data transfer functional to sync 2 database